# Why can't I seem to reuse temp registers in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

The following program 
 1. Prints out the array 
 2. Given a lower and upper bound input by user, determines the min and min index within that range

It runs the print array function.

However, it trips when it tries to store the user input into $t0. (#Ask the user for indices)

```
    # Ask the user for two indices
    li   $v0, 5             # System call code for read_int
    syscall           
    sw   $v0, 0($t0)    # store int in $t1
    sll  $t0, $t0, 2    # relative address position (lower bound)
    add  $a0, $t9, $t0      # array pointer (lower bound)
```

I have tried to use other temporary registers ($t2 ...etc), and it seems to work. But why is that so? I always thought that temp registers can be reused.

These are the errors: 
1. Exception occurred at PC=0x00400018 
2. Bad address in data/ stack read

The full code is below

```
# arrayFunction.asm
       .data 
array: .word 8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 7, 3, 5, 0, 4
newl:  .asciiz "\n"

       .text
main:
    # Print the original content of array
    # setup the parameter(s)
    la $a0, array            # base address of array
    add $t9, $a0, $zero      # store base address
    la $a1, 10       # number of elements in array
    # call the printArray function
    jal printArray           # call function 


    # Ask the user for two indices
    li   $v0, 5             # System call code for read_int
    syscall           
    sw   $v0, 0($t0)    # store int in $t1
    sll  $t0, $t0, 2    # relative address position (lower bound)
    add  $a0, $t9, $t0      # array pointer (lower bound) 

    li   $v0, 5             # System call code for read_int
    syscall           
    sw   $v0, 0($t0)    # store int in $t1
    sll  $t0, $t0, 2    # relative address position (upper bound) 
    add  $a1, $t9, $t0      # array pointer (upper bound) 

    # Call the findMin function
    # setup the parameter(s)    
    # call the function
    jal findMin     # call function 


    # Print the min item
    # place the min item in $t3 for printing
    addi $t3, $t1, 0 
    # Print an integer followed by a newline
    li   $v0, 1         # system call code for print_int
        addi $a0, $t3, 0        # print $t3
        syscall             # make system call

    li   $v0, 4         # system call code for print_string
        la   $a0, newl      
        syscall             # print newline

    #Calculate and print the index of min item
    la  $a0, array
    add $t3, $v0, $a0
    srl $t3, $t3, 2 

    # Place the min index in $t3 for printing   

    # Print the min index
    # Print an integer followed by a newline
    li   $v0, 1         # system call code for print_int
        addi $a0, $t3, 0        # print $t3
        syscall             # make system call

    li   $v0, 4         # system call code for print_string
    la   $a0, newl      # 
    syscall             # print newline

    # End of main, make a syscall to "exit"
    li   $v0, 10        # system call code for exit
    syscall             # terminate program


#######################################################################
###   Function printArray   ### 
#Input: Array Address in $a0, Number of elements in $a1
#Output: None
#Purpose: Print array elements
#Registers used: $t0, $t1, $t2, $t3
#Assumption: Array element is word size (4-byte)
printArray:
    addi $t1, $a0, 0    #$t1 is the pointer to the item
    sll  $t2, $a1, 2    #$t2 is the offset beyond the last item
    add  $t2, $a0, $t2  #$t2 is pointing beyond the last item
l1: 
    beq  $t1, $t2, e1
    lw   $t3, 0($t1)    #$t3 is the current item
    li   $v0, 1         # system call code for print_int
        addi $a0, $t3, 0        # integer to print
        syscall             # print it
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    j l1            # Another iteration
e1:
    li   $v0, 4         # system call code for print_string
        la   $a0, newl      # 
        syscall             # print newline
    jr $ra          # return from this function


#######################################################################
###   Student Function findMin   ### 
#Input: Lower Array Pointer in $a0, Higher Array Pointer in $a1
#Output: $v0 contains the address of min item 
#Purpose: Find and return the minimum item 
#              between $a0 and $a1 (inclusive)
#Registers used: $t0 (array pointer), $t1 (min), $v0 (min pos), $t3 (current item)
#Assumption: Array element is word size (4-byte), $a0 <= $a1
findMin:


    lw, $t1, 0($a0)         # initialise min to the lower bound  
    addi $t3, $a0, 0    # initialise $t3 (current pointer) to lower bound 
Loop:   slt $t0, $a1, $t3
    bne $t0, $zero, End     # branch to end if upper < lower

    sw, $t3, 0($a0)     # store the content of the lower array pointer
    slt $t4, $t3, $t1   # if current ($t3) < min ($t1), store 1 in $t4
    beq $t4, $zero, LoopEnd # if it is 1, go to LoopEnd

    addi $t1, $t3, 0    # store content ($t3) as minimum ($t1)
    addi $v0, $t1, 0        # store the address of min

LoopEnd: addi, $t3 , 4      # increments $a0 lower bound 
End:    
    jr $ra          # return from this function
```

Comment: You are treating `$t0` both as a pointer (via `sw`) and as a simple integer index (via `sll`) -- it cannot be both!  We can `sw` to a pointer but not a simple integer index, and we can `sll` a simple integer index but not a pointer.

Comment: `sw   $v0, 0($t0)` is a store to memory.  If you want to copy between registers, use `move $v0, $t0`.  Presumably other register happened to hold valid pointers when you used them as a store address.

Comment: ok i’ll make changes! thank you